# Different properties of Heavy-Hitters and Count-Min Sketch algorithms?

Tags: approximation, streaming-algorithm, sketching

I'm currently using the Heavy-Hitters algorithm as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37851407/on-heavy-hitters-with-o1-epsilon-space/37851947#37851947) and I'm wondering what if any space, time, accuracy, or real-world performance differences I would see if I were to switch to an implementation of Count-min Sketch plus a linked list to store the "heavy hitters" instead?

As far as I can tell, both require $O(k)$ space where $k$ is the number of heavy hitters to track; both $O(k)$ time to retreive the ordered values; to insert values the former requires $O(1)$ time, the latter $O(\ln{{1}\over{δ}})$. The accuracy and real-world performance differences I'm not sure about and have struggled to find write-ups that aren't too notation heavy that I can understand.